# Mounting docker folder in the host

Tags: docker

I have `/var/lib/home` folder in my docker container and I want to access this folder contents from my computer.

How to map this folder to host?

I'd like this folder to be writable also during usage.

Comment: You can make a persist volume in your container and the persist volume could be in your host. You can follow this [link](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) to do the persist volume.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [bind mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/)

> When you use a bind mount, a file or directory on the host machine is mounted into a container. The file or directory is referenced by its full or relative path on the host machine. By contrast, when you use a volume, a new directory is created within Docker’s storage directory on the host machine, and Docker manages that directory’s contents.

```
docker run -d \
  -it \
  --name bind--mount-test \
  --mount type=bind,source=/path/to/host/directory/,target=/var/lib/home \
  <docker image name>
```

bear in mind the first time when the container is created, /var/lib/home will be mounted from the host and not vice-versa

Comment: "If you bind-mount a directory into a non-empty directory on the container, the directory's existing contents are obscured by the bind mount." https://superuser.com/questions/1344863/mounting-docker-folder-in-the-host